# How can I do web scraping in Julia?

Tags: web-scraping, julia

I want to extract the names of universities and their websites from [this site](https://thebestschools.org/features/best-computer-science-programs-in-the-world/) into lists.

In Python I did it with BeautifulSoup v4:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://thebestschools.org/features/best-computer-science-programs-in-the-world/')
content = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

college_name = []
college_link = []
college_name_list = content.find_all('h3',class_='college')
for college in college_name_list:
    if college.find('a'):
        college_name.append(college.find('a').text)
        college_link.append(college.find('a')['href'])
```

I really like programming in Julia and since it's very similar to Python, I wanted to know if I can do web scraping in Julia too. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tip:
Never ask what packages exist to do X on stack overflow.
Always just ask how to do X.
For two reasons: 1 shopping questions are rapidly closed. 2 get better answers showing how to use package or standard library functions.

Comment: If you'd like to explore yourself, go to pkg.julialang.org and type 'html' in the search field. Also 'xml'. You'll find many packages that allow you to explore xml-like documents.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your python code doesn't quite work.
I guess the website has been updated recently.
Since they have removed the links as far as i can tell,.
Here is a similar example using [Gumbo.jl](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/Gumbo.jl) and [Cascadia.jl](https://github.com/Algocircle/Cascadia.jl).

I am using the built in [`download`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.download) command to download the webpage.
which writes it to disk in a temp-file, which i then read into String.
It might be cleaner to use [HTTP.jl](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl), which could read it straight into a String. But for this simple example it's fine

```
using Gumbo
using Cascadia

url = "https://thebestschools.org/features/best-computer-science-programs-in-the-world/"

page = parsehtml(read(download(url), String))


college_name = String[]
college_location = String[]


sections = eachmatch(sel"section", page.root)
for section in sections
    maybe_col_heading = eachmatch(sel"h3.college", section)
    if length(maybe_col_heading) == 0
        continue
    end
    col_heading = first(maybe_col_heading)

    name = strip(text(last(col_heading.children)))
    push!(college_name, name)

    loc = first(eachmatch(sel".school-location", section))
    push!(college_location, text(loc[1]))
end


[college_name college_location]
```

#### Outputs

```
julia> [college_name college_location]
51×2 Array{String,2}:
 "Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)"  "Cambridge, Massachusetts"
 "Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)"  "Cambridge, Massachusetts"
 "Stanford University"                          "Stanford, California"
 "Carnegie Mellon University"                   "Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania"
 ⋮

 "Shanghai Jiao Tong University"                "Shanghai, China"
 "Lomonosov Moscow State University"            "Moscow, Russia"
 "City University of Hong Kong"                 "Hong Kong"
```

Seems like it listed MIT twice.
probably the filtering code in my demo isn't quiet right.
But :shrug: MIT is a great university I hear.
Julia was invented there :joy:

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

For the purpose of web-scraping, Julia has three libraries:

- [HTTP.jl](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl) to **download** the frontend source code of the website (this is comparable to python's `requests` library) ,
- [Gumbo.jl](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/Gumbo.jl) to **parse** the downloaded source code into a hierarchical structured object,
- and [Cascadia.jl](https://github.com/Algocircle/Cascadia.jl) to finally **scrape** using a CSS selector API.

I saw that you're young (16) from your profile and your python implementation is also correct.

Therefore, I'd suggest you to **try to do a web-scraping task with these three libraries** to better understand how they work.

The task that you wish to do, unfortunately, cannot be yet accomplished with Cascadia since the `h3` is in a `<span>` which is currently not an implemented SelectorType in Cascadia.jl 

[Source](https://github.com/Algocircle/Cascadia.jl#current-status)

Comment: Pretty sure you can do this with Cascadia. I think `span` on its own works fine? Via CSS style selectors

Comment: Also worth pointing out that one could use beautifulsoup itself via the python interface within julia.

Comment: @tasos maybe make a seperate answer showing how to do that?

Comment: @LyndonWhite eh, I'm sure there's enough bad pycall examples in SO already without me adding another one ... :p